# Catching the origin (import) of a FutureWarning

Tags: python-3.x, warnings

I recently noticed one of my programs yielding a FutureWarning, which after some looking around came from SciPy that I was importing (signal_arraytools) and it was easily resolved by upgrading SciPy.

However, this got me wondering if there is a way catch FutureWarnings by their origin. Specifically, I would like to pipe similar warnings that are caused by imports to log file A while the other warnings goto log file B. I can imagine the following pseudo-code doing that but that wouldn't scale well or be easily maintainable.

```
import A # External (e.g. SciPy)
import B # Custom

foo = X
try:
    Y = A(X)
except FutureWarning:
    logger_A("Update external package")
try:
    Z = B(Y)
except FutureWarning:
    logger_B("Fix your own stuff")
```

I would hope something along the following lines is possible:

```
import A # External (e.g. SciPy)
import B # Custom

foo = X
try:
    Y = A(X)
    Z = B(Y)
except FutureWarning:
    # Magically determine which package threw the warning and put message
    # in correct log file
```

I imagine that it is possible to use the package name in the Warning trace to be used to determine which import (if any) caused the warning but I am unsure if it is possible. Therefore, the question is if this is possible or if there is a standard package or method to capture such warnings.

Comment: You could try `except FutureWarning as err_msg:`, log the error message into a single log file, and then do some kind of searching/grep-ing/awk-ing/sed-ing/parsing on that log file. Cool question though! Or perhaps you can make a function to handle `err_msg`, log it appropriately, and have an else statement for unhandled warning messages.

Comment: @ScottSkiles I was considering doing a regex search on the trace itself, although I am not 100% sure that all traces follow a consistent structure. For instance, the SciPy trace at least went along the following lines: "Location: FutureWarning: Message" which is easily parseable.

Comment: Yeah if you can post the code difference between the two, that would be helpful. Are you trying to solve a real-world problem or is this more a curiosity thing at the moment?

Comment: Right now it's a bit of both, I am curious if it can be done, at which point I would deploy it in the package where I encountered it as a message to the user (that they should consider upgrading the underlying package). I also expect that it would allow me to adjust my own code quicker once I have patterns that are going to become deprecated.

Comment: Alright, maybe it would be worthwhile clarifying which one you'd like as the ambiguity makes it a bit challenging to answer the question definitively.

Comment: I don't quite understand which part of the question is ambiguous?